# Should garage have foresaw need for engine replacement, should they have charged me after poor diagnoses?

Tags: engine, gasket

I recently broke down and went to my local garage.  they inspected it and said I just needed a new head gasket and water pump.  After ordering the parts and working on it they said they needed to work on some valves and charged some extra money.  Forgive me I can't remember what the specific issue he said was with the valves.  After doing the work and getting the car started(but still not working properly e.g. its slow, sounds like a tractor, needs to be revved to high to move) he said he couldn't have known earlier but now realized there was a problem with '..compressor..piston...' something(again sorry I can't remember the exact explanation and said the engine would have to be replaced as a rebuild would be too expensive.

Basically they charged me for the first round of work however since it came to nothing they halved the fee.  They then offered to do replace the engine at a reduced rate, however although that's kind of good the total from both jobs still exceeds what they should have done in the first place - engine replacement.

1. Are they being honest when they say they couldn't have been expected to known an engine replacement was necessary and so it was reasonable for them to initially quote me for a head gasket job, or are they just bad mechanics who didn't bother to investigate and I really shouldn't be paying for the pointless work they did so far?
2. Is this type of situation normal with mechanical work.  Should I be content with the fact that they halved the fee and also offered to do the engine replacement at a reduced rate?

Comment: I'd say, it happens. Sucks for you, sucks for the garage. Did they give you a choice between the two options? Without the RO or estimate writeup showing the techs thoughts and tests than it's a toss up. Maybe there were problems with the piston rings or valves to begin with. Being on the service side all I can say is that I'd be happy that they're willing to work with you on this offering a discounted labor rate. Some places don't. If we knew why the engine had to be worked on in the first place it'd help.

Comment: How did your vehicle originally break down?

Comment: @tlhIngan overheating and they identified a leaking water pump.

Comment: @JamesWilson Engines that have overheated often warp. They should have suspected, and they could have taken measurements while the engine was apart for the head gasket work.

Comment: @tlhIngan Ah so you are saying the double job can be put down to incompetence on their part?  This being the case does it change your answer in any way or would you simply say the resolution they offered is reasonable but next time I should go to a more reliable\competent mechanic?

Comment: @JamesWilson Checking for head warp is simple and quick once the engine is apart for a head gasket job. If they knew the engine overheated, they should have checked. The thing about doing this though, is if they find that your head is warped, your engine needs a new head gasket anyways just so it can be put back together, but that won't fix your problem. The real solution would have been to leave your engine apart until it's either rebuilt or replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you went to a mechanic shop, not a wizard guild. The thing is the diagnosis of a bad head gasket is always imperfect. All the diagnosis is telling you is that the head gasket isn't sealing the engine head, not WHY it isn't sealing the engine head.

- Did the gasket crack or rot? Replacing the gasket would suffice.
- Did the engine block warp? A new head gasket won't help, the engine needs to be planed out first (at the very least).

On the other hand, they are charging you for labour that they actually performed. Whether the diagnosis is correct or not, the mechanic spent time on this and should be paid. That's why you brought your vehicle to them, for them to use their expertise and work on it. The intention is to resolve the issue, yes, but that doesn't always happen on the first try.